# Find username in array beginning with 'n'

Tags: sorting, powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a hash table from AD containing usernames and service accounts. I'm trying to find all the service accounts. All usernames are uniquely identified by their first letters such as 'r' and service accounts with 's'. For example: r398831 and s882443. Here's an example of the array I have:

```
  $null = $usrArr.Add([pscustomobject] @{
    sName = $user.name
    sGivenName = $user.GivenName
    sSurname = $user.Surname
    sEnabled = $user.Enabled
   })

$lastSeen = $usrArr | select * | Where {$_.sEnabled -eq $true}
$lastSeen = $lastSeen | Sort-Object -Unique -Property sName
```

I've tried using -contains and -match but it doesn't seem to pull back what I'm after:

```
$svcAcc = $lastSeen | where-object {$_.sName -like "s"}
```

Do I have to perform a for each or have I just messed up my Syntax on this?
I'm thinking maybe I need to sort-object but there has to be a more simple way to pull off something so basic. Appreciate any advice on it.

Thanks in advance :)

Best,
Pete

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-like` operator matches the wildcard pattern on the RHS against the *entire* LHS, so `-like "s"` would only ever match values that are *in full* identical to literal `s`.

To instead match inputs that *start with* literal `s`, use wildcard pattern `s*`:

```
$svcAcc = $lastSeen | where-object { $_.sName -like 's*' }
```

---

As an aside: Your use of `select *` seems redundant; similarly, `-eq $true` is not strictly necessary, so assigning to `$lastSeen` can be simplified to:

```
$lastSeen = $usrArr | Where-Object sEnabled | Sort-Object -Unique -Property sName
```

Note that `Where-Object sEnabled` is short for `Where-Object { $_.sEnabled }`, which is a syntax simplification [introduced in PSv3](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4788.powershell-v3-tips-and-tricks-what-s-new-in-v3.aspx#New_syntax_for_Where-Object), called a *comparison statement*.

Comment: Thank you for helping out. Works perfectly. Yeah apologies on the code I was copying and pasting a bit and forgot to take out the *

Answer (score 3):

You can use `-match` like you were trying to do but just turn your query into a regular expression using the caret anchor character.

```
$usrArr | Where-Object { $_.sName -match "^s" }
```